# Collecting Stickers! Evaluate occurrence of duplicates?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, recreational-mathematics, coupon-collector

> **The Sticker Collector**
>
> You need to collect $n>1$ different Stickers.
>
> Each day you get one pack with $1$ random sticker until you don't
>   collect at least one of each kind. 
> * Each sticker has an equal
>   chance of being in that pack.
>
> $(1)$ What is the chance of completing the collection with $k$
>   duplicates?
>
> $(2)$ What is the average number of duplicates you are expected to
>   have after the completion?
>
> $(3)$ Placing $x$ stickers in each pack, what is the average number of
>   packs needed to complete the collection and what is the average number
>   of duplicates you are expected to have then?

Any answers bringing any progress or insight to any part of this problem are helpful.

---

### My progress on $(1)$

I've found the following things trying to solve $(1)$:

 * $C_n(k)$ is chance of completion with $k$ duplicates and $n$ cards to collect *

$$C_n(0)=\frac{n!}{n^n}$$

$$C_n(1)=\frac{n-1}{2}\times C_n(0)$$

$$C_n(2)=\frac{3n^2+n-2}{12n}\times C_n(1)$$

At this point I'm not sure where this leads, neither how to efficiently calculate the next expression since I'm having doubts in whether the last expression is correct.

---

### Simplest Case $(n=2)$

I've also approached the simplest case.

Since after opening the $1$st pack, we have $\frac{1}{2}$ chance of either completing the collection or gaining a duplicate, we can conclude:

$(1)$ A Expression for calculating the first question in this case:
$$ C_2(k)=\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}$$

$(2)$ Which on average gives $1$ duplicate:
$$ \frac{0}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{2}{8}+\frac{3}{16}\dots = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k}{2^{k+1}} = 1$$

Comment: There are a large number of previous questions on this general subject: search the questions on "coupon". There is a more convenient summary at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parts $(1)$ and $(2)$ are corollaries of the well-known results about the coupon collector's problem, since you complete with $k$ duplicates exactly if you complete after $k+n$ steps.

For $(1)$, the probability distribution for the number $M$ of stickers drawn to complete a set given at [Probability distribution in the coupon collector's problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379525),

$$\def\stir#1#2{\left\{#1\atop#2\right\}}
P(M=m)=\frac{n!}{n^m}\stir{m-1}{n-1}\;,$$

(where $\stir mn$ is a Stirling number of the second kind) yields

$$
P(K=k)=\frac{n!}{n^{k+n}}\stir{k+n-1}{n-1}\;,
$$

in agreement with your results for $k\le2$.

For $(2)$, the well-known expected value of $M$,

$$
E[M]=nH_n\;,
$$

yields

\begin{align}
E[K]&=nH_n-n\\
&=n\sum_{k=2}^n\frac1k\;,
\end{align}

in agreement with your result for $n=2$.

Questions like $(3)$ have been addressed with various variations in various posts on this site:

[Coupon Collectors Problem with Packets: Clarifying Wikipedia](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1650548)

[Coupon Collector Problem with Batched Selections](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131664)

[Coupon Collector Problem with packs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1678841)

[coupon collector problem with groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1729848)